# Is 'riding' okay in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Is it gonna be right if I say this?

> They were **riding** on the train and it turned over.

In this case I'm concerned about word "riding". I think it might be wrong in this case.

Comment: Riding here is correct

Comment: What makes you suspect 'riding' might be incorrect?

Comment: *Riding* is fine in this sentence but not often used.  People more often say "They were *travelling* on the train"

Comment: I'd disagree with @Chris in that I hear "riding" much more commonly than any other verb when dealing with someone using public transportation, and the second most common I would say would be "taking" the train.  (AmE) With "riding", the "on" is optional but not incorrect.  My only gripe about the sentence would be "turned over" - I would say "derailed", or "had an accident".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the use of "riding" in the sentence presented is grammatical and idiomatic; it means we were travelling on the train.  You can ride (on) a bus, train, in a car,

Answer (score 1):

Riding's OK, but the "on" is not necessarily correct, as it might be open to misinterpretation in circumstances where passengers might actually physically travel on top of the train, as opposed to inside.

For example, [photo of people on a train](https://www.theguardian.com/travel/gallery/2012/jun/20/travel-photograper-of-year-2011-winners#img-5) from the Guardian travel photographer of the year 2011